# How do I get a specific version of Cassandra in Embedded-Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, embedded-cassandra

In `Embedded-Cassandra` (https://github.com/nosan/embedded-cassandra/wiki), the default version seem to be 3.11.4. I want to use 3.11.3. I tried setting the version but got error

```
val factory = new LocalCassandraFactory
      println(s"factory is ${factory}")
      factory.setVersion(("3.11.1"))
```

...

Error

`WARN c.g.n.e.c.l.a.RemoteArtifact - HTTP (404 Not Found) status for URL 'http://www.mirrorservice.org/sites/ftp.apache.org/cassandra/3.11.3/apache-cassandra-3.11.3-bin.tar.gz'`

Indeed, the version doesn't exist at 
http://www.mirrorservice.org/sites/ftp.apache.org/cassandra/

How can I use a specific version of Cassandra in EmbeddedCassandra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you get an exception or only a warning message ? 
`RemoteArtifact` tries to download an archive from several URLs.

- https://apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi?action=download&filename=cassandra/${version}/apache-cassandra-${version}-bin.tar.gz
- https://archive.apache.org/dist/cassandra/${version}/apache-cassandra-${version}-bin.tar.gz

The second link works fine for me.

https://archive.apache.org/dist/cassandra/3.11.3/apache-cassandra-3.11.3-bin.tar.gz

Comment: just a warning. Are you saying that `embedded-cassandra` is probably trying more repos? I saw the warning and thought that it isn't working

Comment: you are correct. Though I got the warning, the version i want was downloaded using another repo.

Comment: @Dymtro - I am new to embedded-cassandra and am stuck. Could you please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56181569/how-to-use-embedded-cassandra-without-any-test-framework

Comment: Nosan - I need your help. I have opened this issue. Could you please take a look - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57610622/error-in-testcassandra-a-needed-class-was-not-found-missing-class-com-go