# unable to figure out if my scripts executed correctly in embedded-cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I have created a unit-test which uses `embedded-cassandra` and executes some scripts. But I am not able to figure out if the scripts ran successfully or not.

I see the following two prints (maybe because I have two statements). Is there a way to get the result of the execution and print it on the console.

```
WARN c.d.d.c.Connection - /127.0.0.1:9042 did not send an authentication challenge; This is suspicious because the driver expects authentication (configured auth provider = com.datastax.driver.core.PlainTextAuthProvider)
WARN c.d.d.c.Connection - /127.0.0.1:9042 did not send an authentication challenge; This is suspicious because the driver expects authentication (configured auth provider = com.datastax.driver.core.PlainTextAuthProvider)

  "UsersRepository Specs" should {
    "create keyspace" in {
      val factory = new LocalCassandraFactory
      println(s"factory is ${factory}")
      factory.setVersion(("3.11.1")) //TODOM . shall I pick these fromm a config file?
      val statement1 =
        """
          |CREATE KEYSPACE myspace
          |  WITH REPLICATION = {
          |   'class' : 'SimpleStrategy',
          |   'replication_factor' : 1
          |  };
        """.stripMargin

      val statement2 =
        """
          |SELECT * FROM system_schema.keyspaces
        """.stripMargin

      val cqlStatements:CqlStatements = new CqlStatements(statement1,statement2)

      val cassandraFactory = factory.create
      val testCassandra = new TestCassandra();

      try {
        testCassandra.start()
        testCassandra.executeScripts(cqlStatements)
      } finally testCassandra.stop()

    }
  }
```

There might also be another issue in the usage. Though I am creating `TestCassandra`. I am not passing cassandraFactory instance to it. So I am wondering if `embedded-cassandra` has even started!!

I tried to create `TestCassandra` by passing `cassandraFactory` and `cqlStatements` but I got error `too many arguments in TestCassandra`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to set a **version** from a configuration file.

Do you use any of `slf4j` providers for logging ?

The easiest way to see that your scripts have been executed it just enables *debug* level for `com.github.nosan.embedded.cassandra.test.util.CqlUtils`.

If you don't see any exceptions then there is no issues with scripts execution.

> I tried to create TestCassandra by passing cassandraFactory and
>   cqlStatements but I got error too many arguments in TestCassandra

I think you should use this constructor.

```
public TestCassandra(CassandraFactory cassandraFactory, CqlScript... scripts) {}

new TestCassandra(cassandraFactory, CqlScripts.statemets(...,...))
```

Comment: sorry, can't find `com.github.nosan.embedded.cassandra.test.util.CqlUtils`

Comment: I am using `playframework/scala`. I suppose `Play` uses `Sl4J` - https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaLogging. But I can't find a way to change logging level to debug for `TestCassandra`. I tried getting instance of the logger `val embeddedCassandraLogger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(classOf[TestCassandra])` but I can't find any method which would let me change the logging level.

Comment: I also tried to change the `logback.xml` and added the line `<logger name="com.github.nosan.embedded.cassandra.test.TestCassandra" level="DEBUG" />` but in code `val embeddedCassandraLogger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(classOf[TestCassandra]);
      println(s"cassandra's logger name is ${embeddedCassandraLogger.getName}, debugger logging level is ${embeddedCassandraLogger.isDebugEnabled}")`, I notice that `isDebugEnabled` is returning `false`

Comment: got it working. The issue was that  I am running unit-tests and am using compile time injection, I had to explicitly create an instance of `Application` and also load the `Logger`. Without this, any changes in `logback.xml` will not get reflected in the test environment. `class UsersRepositorySpecs extends PlaySpec with OneAppPerSuiteWithComponents {
  LoggerConfigurator(context.environment.classLoader).foreach {
    _.configure(context.environment, context.initialConfiguration, Map.empty)
  }
`. Changes in logback.xml  - `<logger name="com.github.nosan" level="ALL">`