# Error in TestCassandra - A needed class was not found. ... Missing class: com/google/common/util/concurrent/FutureFallback

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I upgraded my set up to `Play 2.7`, `Silhouette 6` and also updated `TestCassandra` to `2.0.4`. My set up uses `cassandra` `3.11.4`. When I start my test, I get error

`A needed class was not found. This could be due to an error in your runpath. Missing class: com/google/common/util/concurrent/FutureFallback`

How can I fix the issue?

There are few answers in `SO` but they require updating `pom.xml`. I am not using `pom.xml` in the test setup.

Comment: if you are not using maven (pom.xml), how are you handling your dependencies? The issue is caused by a missing dependency

Comment: Could please share a sample to reproduce your issue?